# Apply innerHTML to a var

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I was trying to set a variable with `innerHTML` function But it didn't  work.  Tried the following code:

```
error = document.querySelector("#Error").innerHTML;
```

and

```
error = document.querySelector("#Error");
```

and then change what the text. So did this:

```
btnLogIn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  error.innerHTML="Works";
});
```

Html

```
<div id="Error"></div>
```

I know if I apply this `document.querySelector("#fontError").innerHTML="Works";`
works but I want to avoid this in order to have a better code.

Comment: How do we know you have a DOM Element with the ID of 'Error'? Do you?

Comment: I have with that I id.

Comment: `<div I'd="Error"></div>` is definitely not `<div id="Error">`.

Comment: And why aren’t you using `document.getElementById("Error")`? Also, lowercase; also also, check your console; also also also, don’t use `innerHTML`. Use the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying

```
error = document.querySelector("#Error").innerHTML;
btnLogIn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  error.innerHTML="Works";
});
```

It won't work because `error` will be holding whatever the value of innerHTML is. The following is definitely the way to go because it will store a reference to the matched object itself:

```
error = document.querySelector("#Error");
btnLogIn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  error.innerHTML="Works";
});
```

Are you sure that your HTML is correct?

```
<span id="Error">ERROR TEXT WILL GO HERE</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Your HTML is wrong.  You need this:

```
<div id="Error"></div>
```

Not this:

```
<div I'd="Error"></div>
```

As for the rest of your question:

`.innerHTML` is a property, not a function so you can't make it into a function.  When you retrieve:

```
error = document.querySelector("#Error").innerHTML;
```

You're just reading the value of that property and storing that string in the `error` variable.  `error` is just a string at that point and has no connection whatsoever to the `#Error` object.

If you don't want to do all the work in your event handler, you can retrieve the `#Error` DOM object ahead of time, store that and then use that later:

```
var errorObj = document.querySelector("#Error");
btnLogIn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  errorObj.innerHTML="Works";
});
```

---

But, the best practice is to NOT save DOM objects at all or introduce global scope variables unless there is some specific reason to do so (which I don't see in this case).  As such, this would be the recommended code:

```
btnLogIn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("Error").innerHTML = "Works";
});
```